# Html disappear after using form_error function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to add the form error messages in my html form. Problem is there in first view. In user function html is disappear from where I start to use `form_error()`. My Original form design is like this: [my original form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8dsr.png)
but after adding the `form_error` under the first input: [my form error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5XGd.png) 
Here is my html code

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="name"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
     <input type="text" name="username" id="name"  placeholder="Your Name" />
     <?php echo form_error('username','<p class="p_errror" id="name_error_p">','</p>') ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="email"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email"/>

     <?php echo form_error('email','<p class="p_errror" id="name_error_p">','</p>') ?>
</div>
```

Here is my controller

```
<?php 
    class Register extends CI_Controller
    {
    public function user()
    {
        $this->load->view('files/registration/signup');
    }
    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('files/registration/login');
    }
    public function description()
    {
        $this->load->view('files/registration/description');
    }
    public function registerMe()
    {

            $this->load->helper('form','url');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|alpha|max_length[15]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required',
                            array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
                    );
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('re_pass', 'Confirm Password', 'required|matches[pass]');

             $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
                    if ($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE) {
                          $this->load->view('files/registration/signup');

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->load->model('RegisterUser');
                        $this->RegisterUser->registerme($_POST);
                    }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: where is your validation_errors(); portion ?

Comment: In the RegistersMe I used all validations. but it  cause the trouble in first view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to load the form helper in signup function too.  `form_error` is a function in form_helper. (this is required for other functions with a form view too)

```
public function user()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('files/registration/signup');
}
```

html is disappeared because there was php error. check your error log when this happens or change codeigniter environment to development in index.php